# Let R={f:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}→Z2}Then which of the following are correct?

Tags: ideals

Let R={f:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}→Z2} be the set of all Z2-valued functions on the set [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} of the first ten positive numbers.Then R is a commutative ring with point-wise addition and multiplication.Then which of the following are correct?
a)R has a unique maximal ideal
b)every prime ideal of R is maximal ideal
c)number of proper ideal of R is 511
d)every element of R is idemmpotent

Comment: This is definitely a "what have you tried" moment.

Comment: I also see two other very low quality questions you posted earlier this week. Could you please take a hint and improve the quality of your posts? There is a lot of helpful advice in the FAQ section. Please do not continue the way you are going with your questions.